# Android Simple Calculator App Crashing and Logic

Tags: java, android, calculator

I'm making an android app for a simple calculator. The most important part is that it uses a "rolling" textView, so for example if you did 1+1, then if you pressed another arithmetic operator, "+" for example, the textView would then turn into 2+(enter new number, 3 for example) and then if you clicked multiply, it would then show 5* etc etc.

Right now the error is at line34 showing a null pointer error when I click the number 1 on the calculator. Wondering if anybody can assist me on this / other logic errors if you see them.

Basically if you click to use an arithmetic operator on the calculator, and if there's already an operator in the textView on the calculator, then it calculates the current textView and spits that new arithmetic operator beside it. Otherwise if there are no arithmetic operators on the calculator, it just puts the operator beside the first number.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
if the user clicks a number, then set rollingBar to that number
if the user clicks an operator
    if it is the first operator then there must be only 1 string inside of   
    the rollingBar, so assign that string to leftNum, and assign the first 
    operator type to the text of the button eg. "1".
        get text in rolling bar, assign it to text1, make text2 and assign
        it to text1 + stringButton(which would be 1,2,3,4 etc.. name of btn.
        set the first operator to false

   if it's not the first operator, then you need to calculate by splitting
   the function at the first arithmetic operator, assign the last number
   from the split into rightNum
        switch to the first operator type
        do the math
        assign this second operator to the next rollingBar
```

Right now I'm getting some problems... I'll show a picture and the java file...

```
Picture:
http://imgur.com/35hy4Ze
```

Java File:

package com.example.w0273754.calcfinal;

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.lang.String;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //declarations
        TextView rollingBar;//where all of the text goes when the user clicks a button
        String leftNum;
        String rightNum;
        boolean firstOptr;
        String firstOptrType;
        String number;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            rollingBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollingBar);
            leftNum = "";
            rightNum = "";
            firstOptr = true;
            number = "";
        }


        public void number(View v){
            Button button = (Button) v;
            number += button.getText().toString();
            rollingBar.setText(number);
        }


    //i can click 1 and it outputs 1
    // i can click + and it outputs +
    // when I click next number it just outputs the number, nothing else


        public void operater(View v) {
            Button button = (Button) v;
            String stringButton = button.getText().toString();

            //if it's the first operator being done, then set the rollbar text to text1,
            // then add the operator string to text1 and store it in text 2.
            if (firstOptr) {
                leftNum = rollingBar.getText().toString();
                firstOptrType = stringButton;
                number += stringButton;
                rollingBar.setText(number);
                firstOptr = false;
            }
            //if it's not the first operator, then you need to calculate leftnum and the right num
            else {
                    String fullString = (String) rollingBar.getText().toString();
                    String[] bits = fullString.split("[-+*/]");
                    rightNum = bits[bits.length - 1];
                    switch (firstOptrType) {
                        case "+":
                            add(leftNum, rightNum);
                            break;
                        case "-":
                            break;
                        case "*":
                            break;
                        case "/":
                            break;
                        default:
                            rollingBar.setText("OPERATOR METHOD PROBLEM");
                    }
                }
            }

        public void add(String leftNum, String rightNum){
            int parsedLeftNum = Integer.parseInt(leftNum);
            int parsedRightNum = Integer.parseInt(rightNum);
            rollingBar.setText(parsedLeftNum + parsedRightNum);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

XML file:

```
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/rollingBar" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_column="1" android:layout_span="4" android:text="@string/rollingBar"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonClear" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/buttonClear" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonPlusMinus" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/buttonPlusMinus" android:onClick="onClick1"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonDelete" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/buttonDelete" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonDivide" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3" android:text="@string/buttonDivide" android:onClick="operater"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button7" android:onClick="number" android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button8" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button9" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3" android:text="@string/buttonMultiply" android:onClick="operater"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button4" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button5" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/button6" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3" android:text="@string/buttonSubtract" android:onClick="operater"/>

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/button1" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/button2" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/button3" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonAdd" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_column="3" android:text="@string/buttonAdd" android:onClick="operater"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button0" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="2" android:text="@string/button0" android:onClick="number"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonDecimal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/buttonDecimal"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonEqual" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_span="1" android:text="@string/buttonEqual" android:onClick="operater"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="0"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/errorMessage" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Thank you very much,for the help!

Comment: your layout/xml file?

Comment: Also, here is the error:
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

at com.example.w0273754.calcfinal.MainActivity.number(MainActivity.java:38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         TextView rollingBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollingBar);  // <-- HERE
>         String leftNum = "";
>         String rightNum = "";
>         boolean firstOptr = true;
>         String firstOptrType;
>     }
> ```

You declare a local variable `rollingBar` in `onCreate` which shadow the member variable of your Activity, so the member variable `rollingBar` always null, delete the `TextView`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rollingBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rollingBar);
        String leftNum = "";
        String rightNum = "";
        boolean firstOptr = true;
        String firstOptrType;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure where to post more blocks of code so I guess I will post my answer? Not sure. but I changed things a bit now. I'll put it here in a few minutes

Comment: I've also updated to a new problem and updated the code. All is above

Comment: @GregMiller dont do that. 1 question please. If it's answered, ask a new one